# Payload + Astro Js Integration

Tags: astrojs, visual-web-developer, headless-cms, payload-cms

**Hi! Anyone here knows how to integrate Astro js (planning to use this as the frontend) and payload CMS (for backend) together?**

I know there are existing templates however there are errors regarding npm installation like this one

[https://github.com/Lambdo-Labs/payloadcms-astro-template#readme](https://stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0):

There are two good starting points (take your pick)

Astroad:
https://github.com/mooxl/astroad

Turbopress:
https://github.com/turbopress/turbopress

Astroad assumes you will want to use Docker locally and deploy to a service that supports Docker.

Turbopress is setup as a monorepo and assumes you will want to leverage and use Typescript throughout.

I started with Turbopress as it best suited my needs and made changes as appropriate.